# get css this and value selector from jquery ajax success data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

how get access to desired selector class from internal ajax success settings?

example:
inside form with class 'formdataaj' are located one div with class 'img_ajx',
where i want write text by ajax response.

My problem are that i can't access to selector by $(this). If i put fixed class $('.formdataaj .img_ajx').text(jsondata.image); work without problems, but obviously only in first class 'formdataaj'.

Thanks

my code:

```
$('.formdataaj').each(function(){
        $(this).on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData(this);
        //console.log(...form_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/extra_update.php',
            data: form_data,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(jsondata);
                $(this).find(".img_ajx").text(jsondata.image);
            }
        })
        
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// you need to asign [this keyword] to variable out of success scope 
$('.formdataaj').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
        $(this).on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData(this);
        //console.log(...form_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/extra_update.php',
            data: form_data,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(jsondata);
                $this.find(".img_ajx").text(jsondata.image);
            }
        })
        
    })
    })
```